# ionic/angularjs app construction

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, ionic-framework

When making an ionic app what is the best method of creating different pages of information?

Right now I have separate html documents for each page and a button pointing to each html document; however, I feel like angular/ionic provides a better way of doing so that I missed. For example, the app I am making has a main page with buttons for 5 places. Each button loads a completely new html document with info about the place labeled on the button.

If it is too much to explain, a link answering what I am asking is fine

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want are angular [templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates). You can write a template once, and then pass in information from the controller to take the place of the angular bindings. You have one master template, that changes the angular bindings depending on which information you pass it in the controller.

For example, you could have your application load in partial templates for each location, and display them all on your main page without having to hit a new html document. Check out the example in the [Angular Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02).

And the [Live Demo](https://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-8/app/#/phones)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by uiROUTER, For example: angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']) .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { $stateProvider .state('menu', { abstract: 'true', templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html', controller: 'MenuCtrl' }) / ... / .state('menu.work', { url: '/work', views: { menuContent: { templateUrl: 'templates/work.html', controller: 'WorkCtrl' } } }); $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/work'); });